# else statement is displaying

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this below code when i execuete it it shows no results.But i place no results in if-else condition .Actual result: textbox ,submit button and no results..My expected result is a textbox and button should be displayed and not no results.Without searching a data it displays no reults.So any one help me.

```
        <form action="<?php echo site_url('search1_site/index');?>" method = "post">
        <input type="text" name = "keyword" />
        <input type="submit" id="opn" value = "Search"  />
        </form>




                    <?php
            if($results){
             ?> <div id='hideme'>
             CLOSE<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close'>
            <img  src="<?php echo base_url('img/close.png'); ?>" width="15" height="15" alt="Close"    onClick="hide('hideme')"/>
            </a> <div style="background:#FFFFFF; width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px" id="modal"  >
           <table class="display2 table table-bordered table-striped">
           <tr>

                        <th>course_code</th>
                        <th>course name</th>

                    </tr>
              <tr><?php
           foreach ($results as $row) {
              ?>

           <td><?php echo $row->course_code;?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row->course_name;?></td>
             </tr>
                <?php
                } 
            }else{
         echo "no results";
            }
           ?> 
        </table></div></div>
         <script>
        $('a.modal').bind('click', function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault();
         $('#modal').fadeIn(10);
       });
  function hide(obj) {
      var el = document.getElementById(obj);
        el.style.display = 'none';
         }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `$results` variable is set or not.

Instead you need to check for if `$results` is empty or not.

**Replace**

```
if($results){
```

**With**

```
if(!empty($results)){
```

and also make sure that `$results` contains the array. I mean your variable must have value.

Comment: without searching it displays no results @Dipesh Parmar

Comment: @moses make sure you are querying database to show data for default...before searching records..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your code, $results is not set. Therefore `if ($results)` evaluates as false and else is displayed.

Comment: without searching it displays no results

Answer (score 0):

check the request is a post request or a default page load

use

```
 else if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
     echo "no results";
}
```

instead of

```
else
{
  echo "no results";
}
```