# Without searching a value it displays no record

Tags: php, codeigniter

In this below code i am searching a value.if the value is searched it displays the result but if the value is not present it should  displays no result. In my case if i execute and not search  any value it displays no record .Please any one help me.

```
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('search1_site/index');?>" method = "post">
    <input type="text" name = "keyword" />
    <input type="submit" id="opn" value = "Search"  />
    </form>




                <?php
        if($results){
         ?> <div id='hideme'>
         CLOSE<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close'>
        <img  src="<?php echo base_url('img/close.png'); ?>" width="15" height="15" alt="Close"    onClick="hide('hideme')"/>
        </a> <div style="background:#FFFFFF; width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px" id="modal"  >
       <table class="display2 table table-bordered table-striped">
       <tr>

                    <th>course_code</th>
                    <th>course name</th>

                </tr>
          <tr><?php
       foreach ($results as $row) {
          ?>

       <td><?php echo $row->course_code;?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->course_name;?></td>
         </tr>
            <?php
            } 
        }else{
     echo "no results";
        }
       ?> 
    </table></div></div>
     <script>
    $('a.modal').bind('click', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
     $('#modal').fadeIn(10);
      });
function hide(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(obj);
    el.style.display = 'none';
       }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [else statement is displaying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415474/else-statement-is-displaying)

Comment: what's inside `$results`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `name` attribute to your submit button and check if it's set before the `if...else` block.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="opn" value = "Search"  />

// PHP

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Here
  // Do the search here

        if($results){
         ?> <div id='hideme'>
         CLOSE<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close'>
        <img  src="<?php echo base_url('img/close.png'); ?>" width="15" height="15" alt="Close"    onClick="hide('hideme')"/>
        </a> <div style="background:#FFFFFF; width: 500px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -100px; margin-top: -100px" id="modal"  >
       <table class="display2 table table-bordered table-striped">
       <tr>

                    <th>course_code</th>
                    <th>course name</th>

                </tr>
          <tr><?php
       foreach ($results as $row) {
          ?>

       <td><?php echo $row->course_code;?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row->course_name;?></td>
         </tr>
            <?php
            } 
        }else{
     echo "no results";
        }
} // If closing
?>
```

Is this something similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: @moses, with the code I've posted it will show you search research only when the form gets submitted.  Is that not what you want?  I saw your other question that @Class marked as duplicate and this one and this is what I understood.  Could you may be explain it more, where does `$result` come from? Is the code in your question from the same file or different files etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `$results` is array of results use something like this:

```
if (count($results) > 0)
{
 // show results
}   else
{
echo "No results";
}
```